# Typo3 FE and BE same PID

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

My Typo3 BE-Modul always writes data with PID 1 to the database. On another installation it uses PID11. So I have to configure the FE-Plugin to read the correct PID . How can I configure both to use always the same on every Computer?
My Typoscript:

```
plugin.tx_rere {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_rere.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_rere.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_rere.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_rere.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    features {
        # uncomment the following line to enable the new Property Mapper.
        # rewrittenPropertyMapper = 11
    }
}
module.tx_rere {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$modul.tx_rere.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_rere.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_rere.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_rere.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the constants editor in template module - you should have there at least 2 positions for your ext:

`PLUGIN.TX_RERE`

and

`MODULE.TX_RERE`

set valid `Default storage PID` for both

Comment: I tried "storagePid =123", "storagePid  = {123},  "storagePid = {$modul.tx_rere.persistence.storagePid}" and without storagePid inside the constants. Always with a clean typo3 install + clean database and just my Modul/Plugin. Nothing worked. Thanks for help!

Comment: Tim, use __Template__ module and it's __TypoScript Object browser__ to check if your constants and setup from extension are included properly, and also if there's no override on the page tree i.e. in ext template or some condition.

Comment: TS: storagePid = 1 shows in Object browser [storagePid] = 1
storagePid = {$plugin.tx_rere.persistence.storagePid} shows in Object browser  "[storagePid] = "
[storagePid] = {$modul.tx_rere.persistence.storagePid} in Modul looks correct.